# How to sort an array of objects by their NSString property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, sorting, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have an array of custom objects. One of the properties of these objects is an NSString. I want to sort by that property.

Because it is an NSString and not an NSNumber sorting is a little more difficult. Is there some kind of class method to help in this case? How should it be done?

Answer (score 4):

There is indeed. NSArray has a -sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: method. Call this, and pass an array of one sort descriptor for your property. For example, if your property is "lastName", then:

```
NSSortDescriptor  *desc = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"lastName" ascending: YES];
[array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: desc]];
```

Comment: That works for an array of NSStrings. I'm talking about an array of objects that have an NSString property.

Comment: @awakeFromNib: No, that works for an array of objects that have an NSString property called `lastName`. It will not work with an array of NSStrings, as they do not have a `lastName` property.

Comment: I got it to work using sortUsingDescriptors instead. Did you make a mistake?

Comment: -sortUsingDescriptors will work on an NSMutableArray, I gave an example for a standard NSArray.